# Django Deploying to AWS EC2 (from github)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, gunicorn

Recently I have began to use AWS, I've built a python / django app, and now I want to deploy it onto AWS EC2

This is the first time I have tried to deplay a Django application, so please bear with me, anyway I started with the AWS docs to try and get a app up and running, but found it to be not in depth enough.

I found this Youtube tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjrfUO91wfc which does cover all what I want to do, pull files off of github onto EC2 and deploy.

All was going well until

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/python-django-product-review/prodreview
```

For some reason, directories haven't been created within site-available, the only file I have in there is default.

I have tried to create said files and directories but permissions seems to be a issue too

Does anyone have any advice? or a simpler way of uploading my app to AWS?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need directories inside sites-available, you just need a file. And you need to create it yourself.

Comment: Don't source control your secret key.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, This would be a file in the same directory as the default?

Comment: @dfundako Thanks, completely forgot about that!

Comment: @Cal yes, in sites-available.